# How does --direct parameter in Sqoop export work with Vertica?

Tags: vertica, sqoop

I got `Too many ROS containers ...` error when exporting large amount of data from HDFS to Vertica. I know there is a `direct` option for `vsql COPY` which will bypass the WOS and load data into ROS containers. I also notice the `--direct` in Sqoop Export, [see this Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_3). I'm just wondering if these two "direct" have same function.

I have tried modify Vertica configuration parameters like `MoveOutInterval`, `MergeOutInterval`... But this didn't help much.

So does anyone know if `direct` mode of Sqoop export will help to solve the ROS containers issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--direct` is only supported by specific database connectors.  Since there isn't one for Vertica, you would be using the Generic JDBC one. I really doubt using `--direct` does anything... but if you really want to test this you can look at the statement sent in [`query_requests`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/MONITOR/QUERY_REQUESTS.htm).

```
select * 
from query_requests
where request_type = 'LOAD'
and start_timestamp > clock_timestamp() - interval '1 hour'
```

That will show you all load statements within the last hour.  The sqoop statements should get converted to a `COPY`. I would really hope anyhow! If it is a bunch of `INSERT ... VALUES` statements then I highly suggest NOT using it.  If it is not producing a `COPY` then you'll need to change the query above to look for the `INSERT`.

```
select * 
from query_requests
where request_type = 'QUERY'
and request ilike 'insert%'
and start_timestamp > clock_timestamp() - interval '1 hour'
```

Let me know what you find here. If it is doing `INSERT...VALUES` then I can tell you how to fix it (but it is a bit of work).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried your query. As you hope, it's converted to 'COPY'. Something like "COPY table ( columns... ) FROM LOCAL STDIN NATIVE VARCHAR ENFORCELENGTH RETURNREJECTED AUTO NO COMMIT " So does this mean that every "copy" would generate a ROS container? Because it seems that there are 820 query_requests, while there are 2454702 rows in total and sqoop.export.records.per.statement=3000. In this case, is there anything I can do to reduce number of ROS containers?

Comment: Ok so... not exactly. Notice one thing... the `COPY` does not have a direct keyword.  This should be a WOS load.  This means what likely is happening is that your `COPY`s are actually spilling to ROS.  This is problematic because in Vertica, this will end up create 2 ROS containers.  You would be better of doing a `DIRECT` since at least then you'll only create 1 ROS (even though it is still bad at 820).  If you have a lot of memory you could maybe increase your WOS but I worry it might get you in trouble. Best to use an alternative load method if you asked me.

Comment: I think I will forget Sqoop now. vsql copy from stdin works well at least. It's just not as fast as Sqoop, but still a good solution. Thanks for answering all my questions haha.

Comment: You could just parallelize it yourself. Try this... find a way to split your load up into X parts where X = number of vertica nodes you have. Then make each process select one slice, and connect to a different node. ;-)  Probably won't need to do more than 5 parallel loads, though.

Comment: Also, this might have been mentioned before, but you know Vertica can pull data directly from Hadoop using a connector right?  Really that's the best way.

Comment: Do you mean "Hadoop Vertica Connector"? I just found there's such connector... I'm looking into it right now. Please correct me if you are talking about something else. Thanks. : )

Comment: There are two connectors. The Vertica Hadoop Connector and the HDFS Connector. The former will let you access Vertica from Hadoop for push and pull.  The latter will allow you to create `COPY` statements and external tables and point them straight at HDFS.

Comment: that sounds like good solutions. Have you tested with them? How's the performance, compare to vsql COPY from stdin?

Comment: Just curious, @woot, how did you download the connector for HDFS? I don't even find any download online. I just found Vertica Hadoop Connector. But they are not the same, right?

Comment: that's weird... Because I found https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.0.x_HadoopIntegration.pdf and there is guide for vertica connector for HDFS... Then the documents are really not well organized...

Comment: Well I was wrong. I do see the connector. "HPE Vertica Connector for Hadoop Map Reduce 2.0, supports CDH4" is the Hadoop one I was talking about. I guess they are still supporting it.

Comment: And for previous releases, I see "HP Vertica Connector for HDFS, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and 6".  I am not sure, but it might already be built into 7.2.

Comment: Thanks @woot I am testing with pig-connector from "HPE Vertica Connector for Hadoop Map Reduce 2.0". I will let know if it works. : )